# Connect to user Azure database from SSMS by default

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

When logging into my Azure database through SSMS, how can I make my user database the default? It currently logs me into the Master database, which requires me to manually change the database.

[image]

This error occurs when I try to switch databases with T-SQL: 'use myDatabase'.

[image]

Comment: *"This error occurs when I try to switch databases with T-SQL: 'use myDatabase'. "* That is expected behaviour on Azure SQL Database, which I assume you are using? Also: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why doesn't the method you show work (once you change it from default to your database)?

Comment: Don't edit the question saying solved, add your own answer.

Comment: The real question is why doesn't azure supports USE, very infuriating to work without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@StinkySocks said: The first picture does work. You need to click the 'Browse Server...' option, then select the database. I do not believe it works if you simply type in your database in the box without using the "browse" option first.